# Installing a program on windows vista dutch version

Tags: windows-vista, windows-installer, installation

I have a program that installs on the English version of vista just fine but when we try to install it on a dutch version we get the following error message. Error 1001 "Kan een aantal of alle id-verwijzingen niet omzetten" Google translate converts it to this: "Could some or all id referrals not convert"  This error is happening during the msi install.  Searching on google for this has turned up no results.  Does any one know what I need to do to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this reference:

This says that if you rename the Administrator account it can cause this error:
[http://www.codeplex.com/sqlnexus/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=9486]

Apparently this error translates to "Some or all identity references could not be translated", which I found many results for in Google.